# karma config moving a file to base directory

Tags: requirejs, karma-runner

Is there a way to move a file loaded in the Karma config to new directory, such as `/base/`? I have an external project which contains the source files. I am able to load the file via `../../directory`. However, it inserts the file into the `/absolute/` folder. If I load the test(s) on another computer, the directory of `/absolute/` is different.  Is there a preprocessor or some configuration I am missing?  I searched through the karma documentation, but couldn't find what I am looking for.

```
 // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [   
    { pattern: 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', included: false },
    { pattern: 'node_modules/knockout/build/output/knockout-latest.js', included: false },
    { pattern: 'node_modules/knockout-mapping/dist/knockout.mapping.min.js', included: false },
    { pattern: 'node_modules/knockout-postbox/build/knockout-postbox.min.js', included: false },
    { pattern: '../FantasyFootball/wwwroot/js/site.js', included: false, served: true, watched: true },
    { pattern: 'tests/*.js', included: false },
    { pattern: 'test-main.js', included: true }         
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Karma generates paths that start with `/absolute/...` for files you ask it to
load files that are outside Karma's `basePath`. Karma does this because there's no
simple way to provide a path to these files through the usual `/base/` path that
is both *unique* and *inferable*. If you are to provide a relative path to a
file above `basePath`, Karma cannot just combine it with `/base/`. For instance,
if you had `../my/file.js` and `../../my/file.js` in your `files` array, then
combined with `/base/`, they would both turn into the path `/my/file.js`. For
cases like this, Karma generates a *unique* and *inferable* path by using
`/absolute/` and appending the absolute path of the file on disk.

Ok, so where does that leave you? You want Karma to load files outside
`basePath` and you want to be able to use their paths in your loader's setup.
The problem can be overcome. You can modify `karma.conf.js` to provide
information useful to compute the paths you need:

```
client: {
  absoluteTopDir: path.join("/absolute/", __dirname),
},
```

Then in `test-main.js`, you need to use the `absoluteTopDir` parameter:

```
var absoluteTopDir = window.__karma__.config.absoluteTopDir;
require.config({
  baseUrl: "...",
  paths: {
    foo: absoluteTopDir + "../../my/file",
  },
});
```

I've run Karma for years without any trouble but I recently ran into the problem
you ran into and used the method I described above in one of my test suites with
great success.

I've used this solution both with RequireJS and SystemJS.